# How to put JavaScript date and time using like this Monday, June 28, 2021

Tags: javascript, html

I'm added my code to JavaScript date and time, anyone know how to put date  like this

**Monday, June 28, 2021**

with time and without time

Thanks

```js
const dateDiv = document.getElementById('date-div');

function myDateFunction() {
  const now = new Date();
  const nowStr = now.toLocaleString('en-US');
  dateDiv.innerHTML = nowStr;
}
setInterval(myDateFunction, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="date-div"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a date format options:

```
const options = { weekday: 'long', year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' };
```

And provide a constant of the given format as the second argument for `toLocaleString()`:

```
const nowStr = now.toLocaleString('en-US', options);
```

```js
const dateDiv = document.getElementById("date-div");

function myDateFunction() {
    const now = new Date();
    const options = { weekday: "long", year: "numeric", month: "long", day: "numeric" };
    const nowStr = now.toLocaleString("en-US", options);
    dateDiv.innerHTML = nowStr;
}

myDateFunction();
```

```html
<div id="date-div"></div>
```

To display the time, complete the options by specifying the *hours*, *minutes* and *seconds*:

```
const options = { weekday: 'long', year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric', hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric', second: 'numeric'};
```

```js
const dateDiv = document.getElementById("date-div");

function myDateFunction() {
    const now = new Date();
    const options = { weekday: "long", year: "numeric", month: "long", day: "numeric", hour: "numeric", minute: "numeric", second: "numeric" };
    const nowStr = now.toLocaleString("en-US", options);
    dateDiv.innerHTML = nowStr;
}

setInterval(myDateFunction, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="date-div"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution and valuable guidance,

Comment: @core114, I added a second snippet with time display. Glad to help.

Comment: @core114, no problem :)

Answer (score -1):

```
let locale = 'en';
let date = new Date();
let we = date.toLocaleDateString(locale, { weekday: 'long' });
let da = date.toLocaleDateString(locale, { day: 'numeric' });
let mo = date.toLocaleDateString(locale, { month: 'long' });
let ye = date.toLocaleDateString(locale, { year: 'numeric' });
console.log(`${we}, ${da} ${mo}, ${ye}`);
```

Comment: OP has also asked for with and without time